# XSD schema validation. Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Trying to validate XML schema where the XML contains ids in the elements.

XML:

```
<A:System id="systemName">
            <A:SystemCd>001</A:SystemCd>
</A:SourceSystem>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:element name="System" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="SystemCd" />
            </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Error:

> Exception: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'System'.

Is there a way to continue to validate child elements when parent elements contain IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `id` attribute to the `System` element in the XSD:

```
<xs:element name="System" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="SystemCd" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
      </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```